# How to copy a file from Linux server to Windows server using Ansible playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

I want to copy some dummy files from a Linux remote server to a Windows remote server but I'm not able to succeed. I'm using AWX but the output is throwing an error.

```
ERROR! 'win_copy' is not s valid attribute for a playbook
```

The Ansible version I'm using is 2.9.19 and the AWX version is 21.0.0

This is the playbook I'm trying to run:

```
- name: testing windows files
  hosts: {{ hostname }}
  
  tasks:

- name: Copy a single file
  win_copy:
  src: /path/to/src/test.txt
  dest: user@hostname.domain.name.com:C:\Temp\renamed-test.txt
```

I tried with the "copy" attribute but the output is the same.

Note: I already installed the ansible.windows module but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be syntax error. Indentation is wrong for `win_copy` task. The following code should at least be parsed correctly:

```yaml
- name: testing windows files
  hosts: {{ hostname }}
  tasks:
    - name: Copy a single file
      win_copy:
        src: /path/to/src/test.txt
        dest: C:\Temp\renamed-test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Windoze is weird.  Typically, Windoze has to be running WinRM.

So the first thing is to see whether you can connect at all:

```
- name: testing windoze connections
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:  
  - name: Ping host
    win_ping:
```

If that works, then your `win_copy` will be:

```
  - name: Copy file
    win_copy:
      src: '/path/to/src/test.txt'
      dest: 'C:\Temp\renamed-test.txt'
```

The username needs to be in the variable `ansible_user`, and the password in `ansible_password`.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance man, it seems I'm not  able even to connect to Windows. I'm searching for sort of "how to share files from Linux to Windows" right now, any recommendation for this task? Hehe

Comment: Another question, what do you mean with "The username needs to be in the variable ansible_user, and the password in ansible_password." Where I need to specify those vars? Thank you!

Comment: Those are often put in the inventory (with ansible-vault, so the password is encrypted).

Comment: You have to set up WinRM on the Windoze machine.

Comment: Hi man! I just forget to answer back to you but I actually managed this task using smbclient so that I can copy the file from a Windows shared file to Linux, thank you for the guidance